# Dispatcher has no subscribers after any error

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-cloud-stream, reactive, flatmap

We have a spring-cloud-stream reactive function to handle Message Event, the flux has a flatMap to make external http call with WebClient. Everytime the WebClient get an error, the MessageHandler of the FluxMessageChannel unsubscribes the channel; And then, we're unable to send anymore any event to without an error about the message channel has 0 subscriber. How can we avoid to unsubscribe our handler.

Here is my code :

```java
...

private final WebClient profileServiceClient;

private Function<Message<MessageParticipant>, Mono<ProfileSchema>> getProfile = msg -> {
    final String profileId = msg.getPayload().getProfileId();
    return profileServiceClient.get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/profiles/{id}").build(profileId))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(ProfileSchema.class);
};

@Bean
public Function<Flux<Message<MessageParticipant>>, Flux<Message<ProfileSchema>>> gatherProfile(ProfileService profileService) {
    return messages -> {
        return messages.log(log.getName(), Level.FINEST)
                .flatMap(getProfile)
                .map(p -> MessageBuilder.withPayload(p).build());
    };
}
```

Here is the error message

```java
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:76) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.12.jar:5.5.12]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.12.jar:5.5.12]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.12.jar:5.5.12]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:216) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.12.jar:5.5.12]
    at de.idealo.spring.stream.binder.sqs.inbound.SqsInboundChannelAdapter.access$400(SqsInboundChannelAdapter.java:33) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-sqs-1.9.0.jar:na]
    at de.idealo.spring.stream.binder.sqs.inbound.SqsInboundChannelAdapter$IntegrationQueueMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(SqsInboundChannelAdapter.java:162) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-sqs-1.9.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:458) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at io.awspring.cloud.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.executeMessage(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:222) ~[spring-cloud-aws-messaging-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at io.awspring.cloud.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$MessageGroupExecutor.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:426) ~[spring-cloud-aws-messaging-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at io.awspring.cloud.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$SignalExecutingRunnable.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:310) ~[spring-cloud-aws-messaging-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers**
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:139) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.12.jar:5.5.12]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.12.jar:5.5.12]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.12.jar:5.5.12]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

We try with `onStatus` without success

```java
private Function<Message<MessageParticipant>, Mono<ProfileSchema>> getProfile = msg -> {
    final String profileId = msg.getPayload().getProfileId();
    return profileServiceClient.get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/profiles/{id}").build(profileId))
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, clientResponse -> {
                        log.error("Error while getting profile {} with status code {}", profileId, clientResponse.statusCode());
                        throw new ServiceException("Unable to retrieve profile for profile id : " + profileId);
                    })

            .bodyToMono(ProfileSchema.class);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been brought up many times, so we had to document it. Basically with reactive function there is a common misconception where people thing that we have control of the stream. We don't. . . that is the nature of the reactive API. User function serves as a mechanism for the user to provide a stream (i.e., Flux) that we connect to the source/target stream. Once connected (during startup) it's as if s-c-stream didn't even exist as it has no control over stream and any potential errors. This is fundamentally different in case of imperative functions where function acts as a message handler and is invoked by the framework on each message, thus allowing us to control its invocation and deal with errors.
In summary:

- Reactive function - invoked by the framework only once during initialisation to connect the streams.
- Imperative function - invoked by the framework on every event (message) and is fully controlled by the framework.

More here - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_reactive_functions_support

Basically reactive api provides a very rich set of operation to deal with errors and retries, so we recommend to use those.